# Failed to set up deployment to Azure Web App [AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature]

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-web-app-service, azure-deployment

I'm having a problem setting up a deployment source on an Azure Web App.

Continuous deployment had been setup and was working fine for me before, but currently I can't set up a new deployment any more.

When I attempt to set the Deployment Source for my Web App in the portal: Deployment Center -> Azure Repos -> App Service build service -> choosing my Azure DevOps repo -> Continue -> Finish, it fails with the following error:

```
Repository 'UpdateSiteSourceControl' operation failed with Microsoft.Web.Hosting.WebHostingException: AADSTS700027: Client assertion contains an invalid signature. [Reason - The key was not found., Thumbprint of key used by client: '############################################']
 Trace ID: 02f6d499-09a2-434d-a0cc-8964eca7e300
 Correlation ID: cf1039fd-9244-4469-9a2e-740cfc206262
 Timestamp: 2019-08-22 09:12:55Z
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Security.AADHelper.<HttpPost>d__42.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Security.AADHelper.<GetVsoToken>d__36.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.<GetAccessToken>d__16.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.<GetAccountGitEndpoint>d__21.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.VsoSiteRepositoryProvider.<UpdateSiteSourceControl>d__12.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.<>c__DisplayClass223_1.<<UpdateSiteSourceControl>b__1>d.MoveNext()
 --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
 at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
 at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.AsyncHelper.RunSync[TResult](Func`1 func)
 at Microsoft.Web.Hosting.Administration.WebCloudController.UpdateSiteSourceControl(String subscriptionName, String webspaceName, String name, SiteSourceControl siteSourceControl).
```

I tried deleting and recreating the Web App service, but that made no difference.

Comment: it was Microsoft issue. Already fixed

Comment: Hi Artem, please add this comment to the answer, then this issue can be closed. Thank you.

Comment: Getting the same error today!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was Microsoft issue. Already fixed